# Linux Users can access git client after install...

Tags: linux, git

I installed git using the following steps

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.8.2.3.tar.gz
tar xzvf git-1.8.2.3.tar.gz
cd git-1.8.2.3
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

After doing the above I tye in

```
git --version
```

and I get the following error

```
-bash: git: command not found
```

but it works if I sudo su and then try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have `/usr/local/bin` in you `PATH` environment variable. Try:

> ```
> PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin git --version
> ```

If that works you can add it permanently by editing yoou `.profile` or `.bash_profile` and adding:

> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
> ```